# Instances in DBpedia to template attributes

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia

I need to compute for every instance in DBpedia, (1) a list of Wikipedia template attributes that were found for this entity, (2) as well as the mapping of these attributes to relations in the DBpedia ontology. I know DBpedia has a property that stores the name of the template(s) associated to the entity, however I still have no idea how get the attributes of the template and the associations to the DBpedia ontology. I have searched in the DBpedia documentation but could not find a way to retrieve such information. Does anybody have an idea about how to get this info? Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: I don't think DBpedia stores the template attribute that was used to create each triplet. Could you explain why exactly do you need that?

Comment: Hi, here http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Mapping_Guide, they use the relation <http://dbpedia.org/property/wikiPageUsesTemplate> that goes from entity to template. Then I would need information about the (wikipedia) attributes of that template and the mapping from those attributes to the ontology. I need to know for each entity, which is the biggest set of DBpedia relations that can be obtained from the attributes in the infobox.

Comment: Does my answer covers your question or do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia provides the templates used in an article using [1] and the parameters defined in a template using [2].

The mappings are stored in mediawiki markup in the mappings wiki but if you want a process-able way to access them you might try the RML export we provide in [3] (or [4] if you want all the mappings of a language).
Note that the RML export is experimental and does not take conditional mappings into account.

[1] http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2015-04/core-i18n/en/article-templates_en.ttl.bz2 
[2] http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2015-04/core-i18n/en/template-parameters_en.ttl.bz2 
[3] http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/mappings/en/pages/rdf/ 
[4] http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/mappings/en/pages/rdf/all

(disclaimer: a DBpedia dev)